# Get values from 3 different tables based on specific condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-2

I have 3 tables in my database

1. User (id, username, email, pwd, etc ...)
2. Producer (id, user_id)
3. Address (first_name, city, addressable_id, etc)

Producer has link with User table(User.id = Producer.user_id) and Address table(p.id = Address.addressable_id)

Now I want to get all the producer addresses with his username

I am trying with following query but it is not giving the expected output

```
select u.login, p.id, a.city from producers p

join users u on u.id = p.user_id

join addresses a on a.addressable_id = p.id
```

### My models and relationships

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :customer
  has_one :producer
end
```

**producer.rb**

```
class Producer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :updated_by_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "updated_by_user_id"

  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
  has_many :items  
end
```

**address.rb**

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true

  belongs_to :updated_by_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "updated_by_user_id"
end
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the `addresses` table structure? You are currently joining `addressable_id` to the `producers` unique `id` - you should probably be joining a `producer_id` field on the `addresses` table to the `producers` unique `id`.

Comment: @MarkBannister No I'm not adding producer_id field on addresses table, addressable_id is equal to producer_id

Comment: I wasn't saying you *should* add a producer_id field, I was saying I thought there was probably one **already there** - please reread what I wrote. It seems a bit pointless to have separate producers and addresses tables if they have the same key - remember, "the key, the whole key and nothing but the key".

Comment: @MarkBannister Hey **sorry** for my bad interpretation, Why I am adding address in different table is I have different kind of users like producer i have customer, employee etc., every user has his own address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will want to use the `#select` method of `ActiveRecord::Relation` ([docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select)).

Rails 3.X:

```
Producer.joins(:user, :address).select("users.login, producers.id, addresses.city")
```

Rails 2.X:

```
Producer.all(:joins => [:user, :address], :select => "users.login, producers.id, addresses.city")
```

Comment: Wow will this work on **rails 2.3.5**?? I'll try it and let you know in a moment. Thank you

Comment: Beautiful. I love the cleaness of ruby. The answer I provided was in case he wanted to use raw sql.

Comment: @digaomatias Thankyou I didn't try it through code yet. I am trying in SQL first

Comment: It seems there is no joins method in rails 2.3.5

Comment: I'm getting this error **ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'users' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?**

Comment: You have to have associations between your models. [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/association_basics.html)

Comment: I updated my question by adding models with associations. Do I need to update my models?

Comment: Thank you for your example after executing that I am receiving all producer_ids but I am not getting the exact output

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks ok.

Try changing from "join" to "left join" and see what is the result.

```
select u.login, p.id, a.city from producers p

left join users u on u.id = p.user_id

left join addresses a on a.addressable_id = p.id
```

The reason behind that is that maybe one of the ids are missing, thus removing whole result. 
If this is the case, you'll be able to see some columns with NULL value.

Comment: btw in mysql `left join` is the same as `left outer join`.  The outer is optional but sometimes clearer to read for some.

Comment: I always used just "left join" in sql server. Maybe that's why I think it's clearer than adding one more word to specify the same behavior. Just a matter of preference, I guess.